# How to get $this->translate('Content') => Content in a Textfile

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am looking for a shell script which scans a direcotry and all its subdirectories for .php and .phtml files. Within these files, I am looking for $this->translate('') statements (also $this->view->translate('')) and I want to save the content of these statements in a textfile.

The problem is, that there are several different types of this statements:

- $this->translate('Single Quotes') // I need: Single Quotes
- $this->translate("Double Quotes") // I need: Double Quotes
- $this->translate('Single quotes with %1$s placeholders', $xy) // I need: Single quotes with %1$s placeholders
- $this->translate("Double quotes with %1\$s", $xy) // I need: Dobule quotes with %1$s
- $this->view->translate('With view') // I need: With view
- $this->view->translate("With view 2") // I need: With view 2
- $this->translate('Single Quotes with "Doubles"') // I need: Single Quotes with "Doubles"
- $this->translate("Double Quotes with 'Singles') // I need: Double Quotes with 'Singles'

I have already programmed a script and a guy from starmind.com sent me the following lines:

```
 echo -n > give_me_your_favorite_outfile_name.txt

for i in `find . -iname '*php' `
do
    echo -n "Processing $i ..."
#    echo  "    +++++++ from $i ++++++++" >> give_me_your_favorite_outfile_name.txt
   cat $i | sed -n -e '/->translate(*/p' | sed -e 's/\(.*->translate(.\)\([a-z A-Z \d092\d039\d034]*\)\(.*\)/\2/g' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(\d039\)/\1/g' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(\d034\)/\1/g' >> give_me_your_favorite_outfile_name.txt
    echo " done"
done

for i in `find . -iname '*phtml' `
do
    echo -n "Processing $i ..."
#    echo "    +++++++ from $i ++++++++" >> give_me_your_favorite_outfile_name.txt
    cat $i | sed -n -e '/->translate(*/p' | sed -e 's/\(.*->translate(.\)\([a-z A-Z \d092\d039\d034]*\)\(.*\)/\2/g' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(\d039\)/\1/g' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(\d034\)/\1/g' >> give_me_your_favorite_outfile_name.txt
    echo " done"
done
```

Unfortunately, it does not cover all the above cases, especially the Quotes within Quotes cases. As I am not a shell expert at all and need that script for a verification process, I would be very happy to get help from you guys.

Important: It has to be written in Shell. A PHP Version exists.

Comment: Your last line "double with singles" is missing a double quote inside the closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /path -type f \( -name "*.php" -o -name "*.phtml" \) | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file
 do
    while read -r line
    do
    case "$line" in
        *'$this->translate'* | *'$this->view->translate'* )
        line="${line#*this*translate(}"
        line="${line%%)*}"
        case ${line:0:1} in
            \$) s=${line:0};;
             *) s=${line:1:${#line}-2};;
        esac
        case "$s" in
           *[\"\'],* )
            s=${s/\\/}
            echo ${s%%[\"\'],*};;
           * ) echo "$s";;
        esac
    esac
    done < "$file"
 done
```

Comment: hi levis

thanks for your help. It works almost perfect. I found two exceptions where it does not work:

1. If it is written $this->translate("%1\$s todo", $x), than I need %1$s without te backslash.
2. One thing I forgot to mention in the question (sorry!): If the translate operation contains only a variable (e.g. $this->translate($label) but not a string it should be skipped.

Comment: This script does not properly handle files names with whitespace in their names.  Please see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 on how to do that properly.

Answer (score 1):

This does it using `sed` in a Bash `while` loop and demonstrates another way to do the `find` for variety's sake:

```
find . -iregex ".*\.php\|.*\.phtml" |
    while read f
    do
        sed -n '/[\"\o047]/ {s/$this->\(view->\|\)translate([\"\o047]\(.*\)[\"\o047].*)/\2/; s.\\..;p}' $f
    done > outputfile.txt
```

**Edit:**

To take care of other text on the line change the `sed` command to this:

```
sed -n '/[\"\o047]/ {s/.*$this->\(view->\|\)translate([\"\o047]\(.*\)[\"\o047].*).*/\2/; s.\\..;p}' $f
```

(Just add a `.*` at the beginning and end of the search string.)

Comment: does this take care of strings before "$this" and after translate's ")" ?

Comment: hi levis. thanks for that submission. unfortunately, the outputfile stays empty...

Comment: @Marc: You said "levis" in your comment here, but were you referring to my `sed` answer? If you do the sed command directly on a php file without the `find` or redirection (`sed -n '...' something.php`) do you get any output to the screen? Any error message? Perhaps the `find` is not working. Try a more straightforward `find`.

Comment: hi dennis! I'm sorry to call you levis. Yes, it has something to do with the find because the find itself does not return anything..

Comment: Try it using the find command as shown in levislevis85's answer.

Comment: hi dennis. if I use the find of levis and your script, I get the following error: extra characters at the end of p command

you know why?

Comment: actually. this is the whole error (many many times): sed: 1: "/[\"\o047]/ {s/.*$this- ...": extra characters at the end of p command

Comment: I don't know. Copy/paste the end of the line (this part: `; s.\\..;p}' $f`) into a comment here and let me see if I see something.